# Get compare of time by query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Datatable, with 3 columns.

First is `Datetime`. Second is `UserId`. The last is `Event_name`.

Column `Event_name` has 2 values: "Start" and "End".

I had log event when user start the challenge and when they done. But if user quit the challenge, no event "End" appear. After that, they will start again.

The goal is to get the avg different time between event "Start" and "End" of all Users. From when they Start to End in one season. If they quit - can check manually cause two event "Start" stay together, ignore the first event "Start", and jump to next "Start".

Sorry about my English. But thanks if anyone can help.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output

Comment: It sounds like the design should change to have the Start and End in the same table.  Create event inserts record with start time, end event finds/updates the existing record and adds end date.

Comment: Please read [mre]

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the average for all you can use this:

```sql
select
    AVG(event_end.dateTime - event_start.dateTime)
from
    event event_start
    join event event_end on (
        event_start.userId = event_end.userId
        and event_start.dateTime < event_end.dateTime
        and event_end.eventName = 'End'
    )
    and event_start.eventName = 'Start'
    and not exists (
        select
            1
        from
            event interm
        where
            interm.userId = event_end.userId
            and interm.dateTime between event_start.dateTime and event_end.dateTime
    )
```

It selects all pairs of start and end events for same user, and calculate average.

If you need average time per user, change select to

```sql
select
    AVG(event_end.dateTime - event_start.dateTime), event_start.userId
```

and add

```sql
group by event_start.userId
```

in the end